# Selenium webdriver with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver and getting some problems.

Can any of you give me idea on How to select an item from a drop down list using Selenium webdriver with C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this...

```
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(dropdownobject);
select.SelectByText("ItemText");
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways are there

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*@id='steppersonalInfo']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div")).Click();
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//[@id='steppersonalInfo']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[4]")).Click();
```

And Another way is

```
IWebElement Month = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/div/select[1]"));
SelectElement clickmonth = new SelectElement(Month);
clickmonth.SelectByText("May");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple predefined functions in Select class to get items from drop down in selenium.

```
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(dropdownobject);

1) select.selectByVisibleText("ItemText");

OR

2) select.selectByIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you:

```
protected void SelectDropDown(By locator, string type, string textOrValueOrIndex)
{

SelectElement select = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(locator));

    switch (type)
    {
        case "text":
            select.SelectByText(textOrValueOrIndex);
            break;
        case "value":
            select.SelectByValue(textOrValueOrIndex);
            break;
        case "index":
            select.SelectByIndex(Convert.ToInt32(textOrValueOrIndex));
            break;
    }
}
```